# How to make LinearLayout design in Android?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, textview

I need to make a layout like this in picture:

[image]

Here there is country which changes according to `Spinner` value , and 1 `EditText` where we have to put mobile number. The `EditText` needs to have the format -. The country code is fetched from an API and the number is fed by the user. But, this should appear as one `EditText` only, not as a `TextView` and an `EditText` in a `LinearLayout`.

How can I achieve this?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@drawable/common_bg"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.pigeonmarket.PMRegisterActivity">

    <!-- Login progress -->
    <ProgressBar


        android:id="@+id/login_progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/registerform"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/toolbar_new"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="REGISTER"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="18dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/signup_icon" />



            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/sname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"

                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"

                android:hint="Name"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
                android:id="@+id/fbcountry"

                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/down_arrow"
                android:drawablePadding="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:spinnerMode="dialog"
                android:layout_below="@+id/sname"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />





            <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:paddingLeft="35dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fbcountry"
            android:layout_alignR="@+id/fbcountry"
            android:hint="+"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:textSize="14dp"/>


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:paddingLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/fbcountry"
                android:layout_alignR="@+id/fbcountry"
                android:hint="code"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:id="@+id/calling_code" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:paddingLeft="90dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/fbcountry"
                android:layout_alignR="@+id/fbcountry"
                android:hint="Mobile Number"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:id="@+id/mob" />





        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: where is picture?

Comment: ok wait i upload again

Comment: plz see again i uploaded again

Answer (score 0):

```
create background.xml in drawable & add this as background of edit text & spinner

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#00000000"/> <-- transparent-->
    <stroke android:color="@color/grey" <-- grey color-->
        android:width="10dp"/>
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="30dp"
        android:topRightRadius="30dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: but edit text height width is not as equal as spinner

Comment: this code will create only background you need to give width in your layout xml

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways that you can achieve this,

1. Create a `LinearLayout` that has the background that you're putting in the `Spinner` and other `EditText`s. Give it *horizontal* orientation and add a `TextView` (to contain the country code from your API) and an `EditText` that the user can enter his number in (preferably with `weight` = 1, and no background). This would achieve the same in an easy way.
2. Create a `String` called `countryCode` in code, store the country code from the API in this. Add a `TextWatcher` to your `EditText` and prefix `countryCode` to the input. **Note: changing text of a field within an `onTextChanged()` callback is not recommended as you may trigger an infi-loop**.

Answer (score 0):

i think you simply set api value to edit text first after that if user click on the Edit Text field he can continue type his mobile number after the country code

Comment: gud option ..let me try