# how to set text according to country item in android?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am getting country name from spinner , now i want to set country code according to spinner item in edittext ...but i dont to know how to set according to spinner item ...

this is code (here i am getting country name from spinner):

```
 pmmobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mob);
private void  getCountryData(){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(DATA_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        JSONObject j = null;
                        try {
                            Log.d("Test",response);
                            JSONArray result = new JSONArray(response);
                            //Calling method getCountry to get the Country from the JSON Array
                            getCountry(result);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            }});
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
    private void   getCountry(JSONArray  jsonArrayCountry){
        //Traversing through all the items in the json array
        List<Country> countries = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            String country_name, country_code;
            JSONObject countries_object;
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayCountry.length(); i++) {
                countries_object = jsonArrayCountry.getJSONObject(i);
                country_code = countries_object.getString("id");
                country_name = countries_object.getString("Name");
                countries.add(new Country(country_code, country_name));
            }
            ArrayAdapter countryAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, countries);
            pmcountry.setPrompt("Select Country");
            pmcountry.setAdapter(countryAdapter);
            pmcountry.setAdapter(new NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(countryAdapter,
                    R.layout.contact_spinner_row_nothing_selected,this));
            pmcountry.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                }
                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                }
            });

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("PMSearchActivity", e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
        }
    }
```

i want to set country code in pmmobile..kindly help, new to android.

this is my json:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "Name": "Afghanistan",
    "CountryCode": "AF",
    "CountryIso": "AFG"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "Name": "Albania",
    "CountryCode": "AL",
    "CountryIso": "ALB"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that if you want to display a `String` you are going to use a `TextView`, not an `EditText`.

Anyway:

```
pmmobile.setText(<... string or string res ID ...>);
```

Simple as that.

To keep it asynchronous I suppose that you should put this inside one of your listeners, for example `onItemSelected()`.

Update.
Being not aware of what you are trying to do, I suggest you anyway to browse the constants inside the [`Locale`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html) utility class. You can get all the language ISO codes and what you need from handy constants and utilities from there, without getting crazy with json and similar stuff.

```
Locale.COUNTRY.getLanguage();
```

or

```
Locale.getISOLanguages();
```

Although I don't know if this is what you need.

Comment: actually i want to make calling code with mobile number , i will change that to calling code instead of country code..then i will add mobile number

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42243097/how-to-make-linearlayout-design-in-android/42243434#42243434   in this u can see calling code ..thats how i want to show